# Writing a GCC-compatible wrapper around a .lib file

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, gcc, mingw

I recently received a closed-source SDK consisting of a C header file (`.h`), a library file (`.lib`), and a dynamic library (`.dll`). They were compiled using Microsoft's Visual C++. However, I am attempting to write my code using MinGW (GCC ported to Windows, for anyone unfamiliar with the project). It appears that ld is unable to link to the `.lib` file. I was wondering if it was possible to write a compatibility wrapper between the VS-compiled code and the GCC code I'm writing.

Comment: I'd be shocked if you can pull this off without a herculean effort.

Comment: There are probably only 5-10 functions in the original SDK that I need, if that makes any difference. I know very little about the nitty-gritty of what makes different compilers incompatible.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. There are differences from implementation details that the language spec leaves to the compiler, there are differences from calling conventions, and on and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an ABI mismatch or does it just not want to to link against the object format?  If it's just a linking problem, you can extract the functions you care about, disassemble them, and then reassemble them into an object your linker can handle.  Even easier, maybe [`objcopy(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) can speak both formats and can help you out?

If you do have an ABI problem to deal with, you can do the same but also add a shim layer to thunk the ABI so that the function calls will work.  How complicated that layer is and how difficult it will be to write will depend on the interfaces of the functions you're trying to use.

Don't get too discouraged by the comments - it's software, so pretty much *anything* is possible.

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible; of course it's possible. I said I'd be surprised if it were easy.

Comment: In my experience doing this sort of thing, it takes a little bit of time to massage the disassembly back into something the new toolchain can handle, but that's about it.  If you need to thunk the ABI, that's another effort, but I wouldn't necessarily describe it as difficult - of course that depends on if you're passing `va_list` types around or something, too.

Comment: At this point, it seems like it just doesn't want to link. I point `ld.exe` at the `.lib` file and it tells me it can't find it. Having researched this for the past few hours, it seems like it's not because it's not actually seeing the file but because it's not seeing a useful file. However, corrections are most welcome.

Comment: Sure - that makes sense, if the `.lib` file isn't in a format that your linker can handle.  What error message do you get?  As I said in my answer, you'll probably need to extract the functions using a disassembler and then reassemble them into objects that are friendly with your new toolchain.

Comment: Pretty boring message, just `ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/X-Rite/i1d3SDK/lib/i1d3SDK.lib`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have too many `-l` on your command line?  I wouldn't expect to see the flag in the error message like that.

Comment: @Andy - I see you accepted this answer.  What solution did you come up with?

Comment: I've compiled a library to which I have the source code using both VS and GCC, and am using `objdump` to compare them. Once I know what I need to change from one to the other, I will adjust the `.lib` file. Hopefully everything will work from there.